# how to load tab separated text file and plot in jquery jqplot

Tags: jquery, html, jqplot

I have a text file named: data.txt containing tab separated "time vs value" data like this:

07:32:17    0.05

07:32:19    0.06

07:32:21    0.07

07:32:23    0.08

07:32:25    0.09

07:32:27    0.09

I want to load and plot this data using jquery jqplot pluggin. I have tried in several ways but failed. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is my latest approach using php inside the jquery. Link: http://www.codeshare.io/Ow5kx